# Similar URLs for same page

Tags: seo, canonical-url, duplicate-content

I'm working with a site that uses slightly different URLs for the same content. The sitemap lists the pages as:

```
www.website.com/webpage.html
```

If you surf through the site the same page is found at:

```
www.website.com/webpage
```

Without the .html ending.

This could get fixed using canonical tags, but is it worth the effort when two URLs are that similar? Would a search engine consider them two different pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those will absolutely be considered two different pages. Just one character is all it takes to make two URLs different. Canonical URLs are commonly used for different query strings that product the same content but file extension is no different. Definitely use canonical URLs for pages like that.

Comment: @JMC indicated that he is using [canonical tags](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html), if that's the case, then Google *should* see it as one page, no?

Comment: @casperOne, the way I read it they were wondering if it was necessary to use canonical URLs for two URLs that are the same except for the file extension.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Was wondering if it's worthwhile to use canonical when the file extension is the only difference. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the [proper canonical page link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) on the page, then search engines *shouldn't* treat the pages different.

However, from a SEO perspective, there's no definitive answer one way or another ([Google "seo ranking file extension"](http://www.google.com/search?q=seo%20ranking%20page%20extension) to see what I mean)

What you should be concerned about, however, is that [cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) and that most people have an easier time with remembering pages *without* extensions than they do ones with extensions (do you really want people trying to remember if it's `.asp`/`.aspx` or `.htm`/`.html` based on your platform?).

Additionally, there's a point to be made about the extensions themselves, that they tie the link to the implementation of what's serving up the link (and that this is an implementation detail which is not specific to the content of the page itself).

Comment: The second part of your answer is interesting. I'll vote +1 if you can provide a credible link to information about search engines giving more relevance to URLs without file extensions. Thanks

Comment: @JMC & @John Conde: I seemed to remember it from a long time ago, but looking around, I am definitely not able to substantiate, so I've removed the claim.  I've added some other considerations when using extensions which pertain more to subjective concerns rather than concrete SEO practices.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with useful information. +1

Comment: @JMC: NP, just trying to help =)